Shopify ZIP condition for multi ZIP
I wanted to point out that I'm not a programmer and it's probably a simple thing but I can't.
This function for sending a NEW order WORKS for a zip/zip:

{% if shipping_address.zip == '09036' %}
SU{{ name }}
{% else %}
{{ shipping_address.province_code }}{{ name }}
{% endif %}

But if I want to add many more postcodes, what should I do?
I wrote like this but it doesn't work:

{% if shipping_address.zip == '09036''09037' %}
SU{{ name }}
{% else %}
{{ shipping_address.province_code }}{{ name }}
{% endif %}

Thanks
a simple answer for solve my problem

Go ahead and give this a shot.
{% assign zipCodes_list = "09036, 09037" | split: ", " %}
{% if zipCodes_list contains shipping_address.zip %}
  SU{{ name }}
{% else %}
  {{ shipping_address.province_code }}{{ name }}
{% endif %}

What we're doing is assigning a zipCodes_list variable as a string with your zip codes split by commas since we can't actually instantiate an array natively in liquid. However, by using | split: ", " -- we can turn that string into an array that we can use with the contains check.
By checking if the shipping_address.zip is one of the one accepted in the list, we can then determine whether or not we want to show the SU here.
Hope this helps!
